# session_start() works fine in firefox but not working in chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox

`session_start()` works fine in firefox but not working in chrome. And also I have written `session_start()` at the top of a file but still, it's not working in google chrome.
I have added a check in my code if session is set then a page will be displayed to user. and in chrome it always goes to else statement . In firefox it works perfectly.

```
<?php 
        session_start();
        include("connection.php");
      if (isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



<title>SezaPharma AdminPanel</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>


</head>
<body>



<div class="dashboard">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">All Products</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Add New Product</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Setting</button>
  <a href="logout.php" ><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')" >Logout</button></a>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="overflow:auto">


  <div class="site_wrapper" >




<div class="clearfix margin_top10"></div>


<div class="works01"  >

<div class="container"  >



    <div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-fullWidth"  style="overflow:visible;">


     <?php


    $select_post=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from products ORDER BY PID desc") or die(mysqli_error());

    while($post=mysqli_fetch_array($select_post))
    {

    ?>

        <div class="cbp-item <?php echo $post['PTYPE'];?>">
            <div class="cbp-caption">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    <img style="width:100%; height:200px;" src="UploadedImage/<?php echo $post['PIMAGELOC'];?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <h3><?php echo $post['PNAME'];?></h3>
                            <br />

                            <a href="delete_product.php?PID=<?php echo $post['PID']; ?>" class="cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="Looking Publishing <br>reasonable always">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end item -->

        <?php
        }

    ?>




    </div>



</div>
</div><!-- end works section -->








<!-- ######### JS FILES ######### -->
<!-- get jQuery used for the theme -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/universal/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/style-switcher/styleselector.js"></script>
<script src="js/animations/js/animations.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/mainmenu/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/mainmenu/customeUI.js"></script> 
<script src="js/scrolltotop/totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainmenu/sticky.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainmenu/modernizr.custom.75180.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cubeportfolio/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cubeportfolio/main31.js"></script>
</body>
</html>   
<?php } else{ echo " You mus Loggedin to acces this page"; }     ?>
```

Comment: Reset your browser...

Answer (score 0):

The problem cannot be the browser because they are affected likewise in case of web server trouble. Check if you have cookies disabled in Google Chrome

If you are running your code in your own machine, make sure the local server is online mode; sometimes Mozilla Firefox is flexible in this case.

**Something wrong in you code:** you have `</body>` and `</html>` out of the PHP condition

**EDIT**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("connection.php");
  if (isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



<title>SezaPharma AdminPanel</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png"/>


</head>
<body>



<div class="dashboard">
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">All Products</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Add New Product</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Setting</button>
<a href="logout.php" ><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')" >Logout</button></a>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="overflow:auto">


 <div class="site_wrapper" >




 <div class="clearfix margin_top10"></div>


  <div class="works01"  >

   <div class="container"  >



 <div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-fullWidth"  style="overflow:visible;">


  <?php


$select_post=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from products ORDER BY PID desc") or die(mysqli_error());

while($post=mysqli_fetch_array($select_post))
{

?>

    <div class="cbp-item <?php echo $post['PTYPE'];?>">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                <img style="width:100%; height:200px;" src="UploadedImage/<?php echo $post['PIMAGELOC'];?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                        <h3><?php echo $post['PNAME'];?></h3>
                        <br />

                        <a href="delete_product.php?PID=<?php echo $post['PID']; ?>" class="cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="Looking Publishing <br>reasonable always">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end item -->

    <?php
    }

?>




</div>



 </div>
 </div><!-- end works section -->








  <!-- ######### JS FILES ######### -->
  <!-- get jQuery used for the theme -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/universal/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/style-switcher/styleselector.js"></script>
  <script src="js/animations/js/animations.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="js/mainmenu/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/mainmenu/customeUI.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/scrolltotop/totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainmenu/sticky.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainmenu/modernizr.custom.75180.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cubeportfolio/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cubeportfolio/main31.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html> 
  <?php } else{ echo " You mus Loggedin to acces this page"; }   ?>
```

Comment: Cookies are enabled in my chrome browser i have checked it.

Comment: Tested the code? That mistake could make that error in the browser. I cannot test it now

Comment: If you want just copy it

Comment: **Did you copy it?** Here it works perfectly in all browsers (including Google Chrome)

Comment: What's your web server? is it online? Did you restarted the Chrome as @Huy Trịnh said? In this case restart the machine too

Comment: Its online Cpanel.

Comment: Could you give me the url? Thus far as we go i cannot help more without more info